# Why the method InitializeComponent throw an error?

Tags: xaml, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime

I have created a new SplitPage inside VS2012 and I load this page with:

```
this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(SplitPage), "AllGroups");
```

An error is throw from :

```
this.InitializeComponent();
```

Visual Studio show me this exception :

```
An exception of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred
in IC2.exe but was not handled in user code
WinRT information: Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key SubtitleTextStyle
[Line: 88 Position: 104]
```

If I catch the error I found the message :

```
Unspecified error
```

How can I avoid this error ?

Comment: Have you added any content to your SplitPage or its code-behind?

Comment: I just left the code generated by VS2012 untouched.

Comment: Close VS and reopen the project. Basically, 'have you tried turning it off and on' - It-Crowd. I've had some weird things happen in VS2012, restarting or just cleaning the solution works sometime.

Comment: I've tried to restart but no luck this time...

Comment: If I disable _"TOOLS>Options>Debugging>General>Enable Just My Code"_ I haven't the error but the page don't load...

Comment: I don't understand why but the problem don't occur with an _Items Page_.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies in the xaml where you don't have the style in the resources that is being call "SubtitleTextStyle". You may want to check on that or remove that line away in your xaml.